# Class to JSON object using ArraySegment

Tags: c#, arrays, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I am trying to figure out this problem,

I want to transfer Json object using ArraySegment

my JSON Data is 
in this format

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

I have used [this](http://json2csharp.com/) tool to create specified class like

```
public class Employee
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; }
}
```

now I am inserting data into object like this

```
var objectToSerialize = new RootObject();
objectToSerialize.items = new List<Employee> 
          {
             new Item { firstName="abc", lastName="xyz"},
             new Item { firstName="pqr", lastName="stu"}
          };
```

but now I am facing problem, I don't know how to send it using 
websocket

through this

```
ArraySegment<byte> max = new ArraySegment<byte>(, , );
await webSocket.SendAsync(max, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to serialize the objectToSerialize into a buffer of bytes first

```
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);
var encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
var buffer = new ArraySegment<Byte>(encoded, 0, encoded.Length);
await webSocket.SendAsync.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
```